# How can I use Exim4 to forward email for root to another email address?

Tags: debian, email, exim

I am trying to forward system email (from apt, cron, etc.) addressed to "root" to my personal email address using a smarthost. I am using Debian 9. First, I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`. This is the contents of `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` (I replaced all occurrences of my domain name with "example.com"):

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='satellite'
dc_other_hostnames=''
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
dc_readhost='example.com'
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='mail.messagingengine.com::587'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='true'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

I also set the correct password in `/etc/exim4/passwd.client` I can now successfully send mail to any email address with `sendmail`, `mailx`, etc.

Second, I edited `/etc/aliases` to contain the following:

```
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
root: my-email-address@example.com
```

But, when I try to send an email to "root" with `echo Hi | mailx root` I see the following error in `/etc/exim4/mainlog`:

**SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<root@example.com>: 550 5.1.1 <root@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table**

I thought I told Exim4 to redirect email for root to "my-email-address@example.com". But instead it is redirecting it to "root@example.com". Why is Exim4 not honouring my `/etc/aliases`? How should I setup Exim4 to redirect email for root to my personal email address?

Answer (score 2):

The `satellite` configuration sends ALL email to the specified smarthost. No local delivery is considered, so the `/etc/aliases` file is not consulted.

If you want to have local delivery considered you should change the configuration type from `satellite` to `smarthost`.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check /etc/email-adresses
--> https://manpages.debian.org/testing/exim4-config/etc-email-addresses.5.en.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/540617)