# Exim4 email forward not working

Tags: email, exim, alias

I have been trying to set up an email forward on my server, which uses Exim 4. I want to forward all emails sent to steve@mydomain.com to john@mydomain.com.

From reading elsewhere and [looking at a previous answer on here](https://serverfault.com/questions/734773/how-can-i-use-exim4-to-forward-email-for-root-to-another-email-address) I understand I need to edit /etc/aliases in order to do this. From looking in there I saw several forwards had already been set up:

```
# /etc/aliases
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
root: user
```

I decided to test one of these first but when I sent an email to webmaster@mydomain.com I got a Delivery Status Notification (Failure) stating "The email account that you tried to reach does not exist."

Just in case, I tried adding this line to the file:

```
steve: john
```

But no success, also:

```
steve@mydomain.com: john@mydomain.com
```

Didn't work either.

There must be something about how this works which I don't understand. It seems strange to me that the default ones like webmaster aren't working to begin with. I'm not the person who set the server up and I'm not able to contact the person who did, so if anyone can help point me in the right direction with this I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you have edited the `aliases` file you should run `newaliases` command to compile config file into the database used by MTA.